# How to select number content in element and add commas with jquery or js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to simply add commas to numbers in my code. I have tried a lot of hints here but something seems to be wrong.

I have tried with regex and the `toLocalString()` method and both haven't worked, can someone help me find the correct solution.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
      // $("#price").toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',')
      $('#price').html.toLocaleString('en');
   });
</script>
```

Here's my element:

```
<strong id="price"><%# Eval("OfferPrice") %></strong>
```

Everything seems ok, can anyone help please. Thanks a lot!

Comment: To clarify your question, are you trying to add commas after any instance of a number? If so I don't see any number in the string- 'Everything seems ok, can anyone help please. Thanks a lot!'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

Comment: Its an ASP.Net project; the number, is pulled from a databind in codebehind using the <%# Eval("OfferPrice") %> which outputs the rate

Comment: This is the output on the page: Budget: 
```1000000
Job Specification Document(Opens in New Window): View/Download 
Task Description: 
```

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to add commas after any instance of a number, you need to have a number in the output string 'Everything seems ok, can anyone help please. Thanks a lot!'

Comment: Its an ASP.Net project; the number, is pulled from a databind in codebehind using the <%# Eval("OfferPrice") %> which outputs the rate

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) :

```
parseFloat($('#price')).toLocaleString('en-US');
```

You need to specify that the value of `#price` is of type number (float), then you can apply toLocalString() function with your desired formatting country.

Comment: I have done this, still it doesn't work. `parseFloat($('#price')).toLocaleString('en-US')`  and also: `function numberWithCommas(x) {
            return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        }
              numberWithCommas(('#price'))`

Answer (score 0):

So, I finally found a 'mix' from the answers; that works. Here's the code. Thanks guys... and I will still need more help

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

        var x = parseFloat($('#price').html()).toLocaleString('en-US');
         $('#price').html(x)


   });
```

Works awesome but will render only the first instance; how do I make it run through every instance of id="price" in the DOM? Thanks a lot friends.

Answer (score 0):

Replace in your DOM all `id` attributes by `class` attributes, then you can render all values by your desired formatting.

Your DOM elements will be edited as follow :

```
<strong class="price"><%# Eval("OfferPrice") %></strong>
```

From [jQuery Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var x = parseFloat($('.price').html()).toLocaleString('en-US');
        $('.price').html(x)
 });
```

Comment: This just renders the value of the first element across all elements with the same class, so instead of 1,000... 3,000, 12,000; I have 1,000 across all. This is what I have also tried `$('#price').each(function () {

                var x = parseFloat($('#price').html()).toLocaleString('en-US');
                $('#price').html(x);

            });` but this still affects only the first element with selected id